# Erlang Dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, erlang

I *think* I know the answer already, but wanted to make sure.  I'm constructing a dictionary to serve as a static lookup table (i.e., the dictionary will be immutable once it's created), and have found that this serves the purpose:

```
L = [{keyA, "A"}, {keyB, "B"}, {keyC, "C"}].
D = dict:from_list(L).
V = dict:fetch(keyA, D).
```

Is this an acceptable method or is there some other magic I'm not yet familiar with?

As a follow-up, if I were creating a mutable dictionary, does one really have to entertain machinations such as

```
D  = dict:from_list(L).
D1 = dict:append(keyD, "D", D).
```

And finally, rather than passing the dictionary around from function to function, is there a persistent store I can stash and retrieve it from, along the lines of the `register/2`-`whereis/1` routine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that is an acceptable method.

If you want to modify your dictionary, you always need to get the return values from all operations which modify your dictionary, as Erlang only has immutable data. This is the normal way to handle all Erlang data, so you will very quickly get used to it.

An alternative is to use [ets](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) which is another way of storing data. Depending on how you create an ets table you may or may not need to carry around a reference to it. The data in ets tables is not stored in the process heap so accessing it entails copying between the process and the ets data, however ets tables are generally better at storing large amounts of data. Whether it is better to use dict/orddict/gb_trees or ets depends very much on the data you intend to store and what operations you mean to do on it.

Comment: Re: ets tables, is the recommendation to create a global table for storing all various global variables, whether they be a dict, orddict, atom, etc., or is it preferred to say, create an ets table specifically to serve as a dictionary?  In other words, if I needed to store 3 atoms and 1 dict, should one create a single ets table with 4 keys (3 pointing to atoms, 1 pointing to a dict of keys and values), or a two ets tables, one containing 3 unrelated atoms and another containing key-values acting as a dict.

Comment: @Joe You should **NOT** store a dict in an ets table as this would mean you copy the whole dict every time you access it, which is a Bad Thing. In this case it is better to use an ets table instead of the dict. You can have many ets tables and use them for different things. If you use named ets tables then all processes can share these tables. N.B. that ets tables are data stores and not data bases so there are only **very** limited transactions on them. With a dict the process can keep complete control of it.